# Error when using the MERGE command in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to update or insert data into a table using the `MERGE` command in DB2 v11. However I keep getting the error:

> SQL0723N  An error occurred in a triggered SQL statement in trigger "TRACE_AFTE".
>   Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-746", SQLSTATE "57053" and message tokens 
>   "CUSTOM_AFTER_UPDAT|SP_CUSTOM_AFTER_U".  SQLSTATE=09000"

I looked up the error and it said that the routine conflicted with the use of the table..that the table is already in use.

I've tried changing the query to update based on `VALUES` instead of table but get an error on an unexpected token

> SQL0104N  An unexpected token "INSERT" was found following "MATCHED        THEN".
>     Expected tokens may include:  "".  SQLSTATE=42601
>   "

```
MERGE INTO TRACE target 
USING IMPORT_RAW source
     ON target.DETAIL_NUMBER = source.DETAIL_LINE_ID
          AND target.DESC = source.TRACE_TYPE
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET NUMBER = source.PRO
```

With   `VALUES`

```
MERGE TRACE AS T
USING IMPORT_RAW AS S
      ON (T.DETAIL_NUMBER= S.DETAIL_LINE_ID) AND T.DESC = S.TRACE_TYPE
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET     
THEN INSERT(DETAIL_NUMBER, TRACE_NUMBER) VALUES(S.DETAIL_LINE_ID, S.CARRIER_PRO)
WHEN MATCHED 
     THEN UPDATE SET T.NUMBER= S.PRO;
```

The query should update multiple records from the `Import_raw` table where the record exists and import where it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What type of triggers are defined? Check out the rules for MERGE https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  It seems like the problem was that it was trying to merge the same record twice.  My truncate table had been commented out.